# How to enumerate images on A4 print for multiple pages on Phtoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, photoshop-scripting, javascript, postscript

I have to print some labels on an A4 paper. These labels need to be enumerated with iteration for multiple prints. About 8 labels per page, and more than 10-15 pages, depending on the requirement.

I searched online and found that postscript allows some script functionality at the time of print. I tried reading some postscript examples, but couldn't find any valid example to suggest an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

Although I know some javascript, and maybe there's a script for this in the jsx Extended Script somehow.

Example:
o

```
n.event.print(){
smartobject_label(all){ .          //all the smartobjects (labels)
for(i=0;i<=all.length;i++){
smartobject_label(this).object(number_object.text).text=i+1;
                                          //(i+1)=starting from 1;
                       }
                   }
}
```

That's mostly all.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/115084/photoshop-batch-add-incremental-serial-number-on-image

Comment: @Scott, it seems to me (although it is a bit unclear) that the OP wants the numbering to be visible on print - not to export files with incremental serial numbers.

Comment: @wolff: Yes, I need the enumeration to be printed on the A4 paper. It's not for filenames... Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with InDesign or Illustrator? I believe it would be much easier to do in one of those applications. There are several ways to do it, but it depends on the layout and how you have constructed your file.

Comment: I've got an A4 paper with 4 rows and two columns of duplicated smart objects of an image file. Nothing else on the document apart from these smart object layers.

Comment: Note the votes.. If' I'd have voted to close this as a duplicate, it would have been closed. I merely posted the *possible* duplicate to provide additional, possibly helpful, information. I guess I should have used "possibly related". As far as I'ma ware, you can't generate auto-numbering in photoshop itself for output. It's simply not designed for that. But.... I could be wrong. `:)` often am,

Comment: @Scott is right, Photoshop is probably the wrong tool for the job. Using Photoshop for print designs will keep giving you problems like this. If you instead only use Photoshop for image editing and then start to use InDesign or Illustrator for print layouts, it will end up being a big relief - it was for me. That said, it is probably possible to make a script for it, but I don't think it's possible to add content when you print. You probably have to create an image for each page. And the code will grow from your example: which font/size/color/position/alignment etc.?

Comment: Thanks Scott... I read that Print Options in Photoshop allow Postscript to be added. I guess I could possibly find some way to generate the iterated enumeration with that option. _I tried finding where I read about this option, but cannot find the page now_

Comment: @Wolff: Does Gimp allow this? Can I use photoshop for the smart object layout, and then a photoshop action with script to open the document in gimp for the printout?

Comment: Making Photoshop and Gimp work together sounds like a bad idea. The idea of scripting this sounds overly complicated and hacky. It's pretty easy to do in a vector based application so why go through the trouble?

Comment: Ok. Thanks! I'll try and use a vector application.

Comment: Could I request question this to be closed?